# Apple MacBook Pro 2013 with 512Gb SSD cannot install OS X

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, disk-format, core-storage

I had an issue running an App and the vendor suggested I should revert to the earlier OS X 10.10.3.

I located on Time Machine the backup version I needed, waited for the format and restore. I then needed to repeat the process of restoring from Time Machine, but now the MacBook is in a stupid state.

The system starts with OS X Utilities. Restore from Time Machine backup gets me to the point where it wants to know the destination drive, but my SSD doesn't show up.

Same thing if I choose Reinstall OS X.

If I select Disk Utility, I can see the SSD as "Macintosh HD" and I can see "First Aid" and "Partition" but no "Erase". If I select "Verify Disk" or "Repair Disk", the log shows that everything is working fine....it is 499.42Gb in size. The OS X Base System volume is also there....

So without seeing "Macintosh HD", I cannot recover from Time Machine or Reinstall OS X.

I am stuck, any ideas folks?

---

**Follow-up:**

Thanks for your kind reply.  To explain again:

1. I restored a Time Machine version of OS X 10.10.3, then I did some work and then decided to recover the same version of Time Machine backup a 2nd time.
2. The second restore of OS X 10.10.3 failed.
3. Using Disk Utility, I can see the "Macintosh HD" volume, but only the tags "First Aid" and "Partition" are shown.

I followed your procedure described above to create a USB boot system.  The following happened:

1. A 4Gb USB stick was declared by the system as being too small.
2. I eventually found a 16Gb USB stick and the download proceeded, but when the system was in "Setting up...." mode, I got a warning that the memory was too small and that memory was nearly full.  A short while later I got a "Memory Full" error!!! and nothing further other than the spinning wheel and a waste of time.
3. Next day I went to the store and bought a 64Gb USB stick.  When I started the system copy process, the Internet was having issues it I received a notice that the process would take around 738hrs!!!!
4. Eventually I got to a 2hrs15min download and the process completed, except the notice that my system would restart in 10secs never happened....I clicked the "Restart" soft key and off we went.  10hrs later I was still seeing the "Setting up...." message and the occasional flicker of the USB LED.
5. I then found a bootable OS X 10.8.2 and restarted my Macbook Pro.
6. Using the Disk Utility, I can see the "Macintosh HD", but again only the "First Aid" and "Partition" tabs are shown.
7. This time when I do a "Repair Disk" I get the messages:
   "disk0s2 has CoreStorage features not supported by this fsck_cs version"
   "Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map"
   "Error: This disk needs to be repaired. Click Repair Disk."
8. Clicking "Repair Disk" just brings me to the same messages.

If I could just "Erase" my "Macintosh HD" volume, I would be good to go.....frustrating!

Comment: I revised my answer to incorporate the additional infos given by you

Answer (score 1):

Usually you shouldn't be urged to restore the backup twice. Probably something went wrong in the first and/or the second run.

To quickly resolve your problem boot to Internet Recovery Mode or an external drive/thumb drive containing a Recovery HD or full OS X, erase/reformat your internal drive and restore the 10.10.3 backup. If you boot to IRM or a second drive you may manipulate the internal disk without any restrictions.

Just erasing a volume is not recommended because it might not recover any faulty or wrong partition table. So better repartition the drive.

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. The prerequisites for an Internet Recovery are listed here: [Recovery/Internet Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718).
  In a few words you need the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated for a successful internet recovery.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into the Recovery Netboot image which is loaded from an Apple server.

  (Alternatively you may boot to an external drive containing a Recovery HD or a full OS X system or an OS X thumb drive.)
- open Terminal and enter:

  ```
      diskutil cs list
  ```
- copy the UUID of the Logical Volume Group (it's the first one listed) and enter:

  ```
      diskutil cs delete UUID
  ```

  **The content of the main volume will be lost doing that. A backup is required.**
- Quit Terminal and open "Disk Utility" and partition your internal disk: GUID partition scheme (use the "Options..." button at the bottom of the main pane for this), one partition, journaled HFS+.
- Close "Disk Utility".
- Attach your Time Machine backup drive.
- Open "Restore from Time Machine Backup" and restore your main drive if you have booted from a Recovery drive.
  If you've booted from a full OS X external drive just open Time Machine and restore your internal drive.